# Serve cookie free URLs in WordPress without using a CDN

Tags: php, javascript, performance, wp-config, cookies

I ran a GTmetrix test on my site (`example.com`) and got a very low score (50) for "coockie free domains". I gather from this error that the webpage of each URL of my domain is served with cookie recording.

But, I don't want to record cookies for any of my users. I have no usage in these cookies and shouldn't have one in the horizon.

I read that a CDN can do it for me and prevent me of getting the error due to slow self-serving of webpages with cookie-recording, but I also don't desire to use a CDN to serve cookie free URLs for my domain.

Thus, I pasted this in the very end of `wp-config.php` of my site, and saved:

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.example.com"); 
define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "example.com");
```

After pasting this, I've noticed it requires a subdomain from which to record cookies, but I don't want to use a subdomain at all.

How could I serve webpages without gathering any cookies, in my WordPress website, without using either a CDN or a subdomain. I just don't want to gather any cookies in that time.

Comment: WordPress doesn’t set cookies for site visitors. It sets cookies for admin user logins and for people commenting on posts. You may have a plugin or theme that sets cookies. GTMetrix may also just be testing whether your domain can set cookies rather than whether it does and you should analyse your site server headers to be sure.

Comment: Is there a way to totally disable all cookies whatsoever?

Comment: Turn off all commenting. I don’t believe that GTMetric is telling you what you think it is telling you.

Comment: not sure what the question is. If you want cookie free requests, just don't set cookies.

Comment: I turned off all commenting and I still have the problem. @MarkKaplun I didn't set any cookies but I still get the error. This might come from a plugin but I don't know which and how to set these down so I look for a general way because either way I don't want cookies at all.

Comment: your problem is using GTMatrix (pagespeed is not better). It gives you irrelevant scores, in the sense that to implement the suggestions in wordpress will require either much coding effort or will create annoyance in the editing flow. To do what they recommend you need to use a different domain or subdaim for your static resources, which is what they are actually checking, and they give you a recomendation based on the possibility that you might have set cookies, which you don't.... the recomendations of those tools need to be taken with many grains of salt

Comment: Turn off all your plugins. Set a default theme such as twenty seventeen. Run GT Metrix. If it still complains (it’s wrong to call this an error) then you know that it is testing the capability of your domain to set cookies, not the fact that it does. If it now says your domain is cookieless then test again with your preferred theme. Then re-enable plugins one by one testing as you go and see which causes a change.

Comment: @MarkKaplun yeh I don’t rate GTMetrix but it and SmushIt are in all of the “me too” SEO and site performance blog posts clogging up the web so people use it in an uninformed way.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook, well people need to decide, they want productivity for (almost) zero money, or want to be ranked (maybe) one place higher in google. The problem with people like the OP (based on the tone of the question) is that they want to be ranked higher without doing any true development effort, or pay some extra money.